Emulator output log for startup failure
Estou tento problema ao coda o beeware. mais especificamente estou tentando rodar o briefcase run android porém estou tento erro.enter image description here
briefcase create android
briefcase build android
briefcase run android.
eu esperava que o aplicativo me mostrasse uma tela do emulador android. mais não aparece e da erro.
